# Load script in HTML after retrieving backend data via angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I retrieve some HTML from database via angular and bind it on frontend with $sce.trustAsHtml. There is script that does some actions on retrieved HTML.

Angular controller:

```
$scope.Page= response.data;
$scope.pageContent = $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.Page.Content);
```

In page html file:

```
<div ng-bind-html="pageContent">
```

And there is script file which is loaded inside page html file:

```
<script src="scripts/script.js"></script>
```

This script must be executed after `$scope.Page= response.data`

What I tried is to use:

```
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
       setTimeout(function(){
         // script code
    }, 2000);
 });
```

And it works, but script file is however loaded immediately after page html file is loaded, it just timeouts "script code". I want to postpone script loading until I retrieve `$scope.Page= response.data;` 
Is there angular directive or something to use on  element to load it after $scope.Page is available or some other solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can manually create a `<script>` element and set its `src` attribute to the desired URL after the HTML content is bound:

```
var tag = document.createElement('script'),
    firstScript = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];

tag.src = 'scripts/script.js';
firstScript.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScript);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, I would recommend you to store the script content in a cdn url or else you can store it in **$templateCache** in the `application`. Check the below sample for better understanding.

```js
function sampleController($scope, $templateCache) {
   
  //templateCache will store the template/script
  $templateCache.put('myScript', 'alert("hi")');

  //function to execute at a point of time
  $scope.executeScript = function() {
    var scriptContent = $templateCache.get('myScript');
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.textContent = scriptContent;
    document.head.appendChild(script);
  };
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-controller="sampleController" ng-app>
  <button ng-click="executeScript()">Execute Script</button>

</div>
```